# How can ignore more than one commands from history?

Tags: linux, unix, history

If we want to remove one command from history we can use,

For Example,

export HISTIGNORE="ls" -> It will remove the ls command from history.

But I want to know how to ignore more than one commands from history?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input the list with commands separated by colons:

```
export HISTIGNORE="&:ls:[bf]g:exit"
```